# Shell script: call command containing variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

What is wrong with this script?

```
#!/bin/sh
SONAR="~/SonarQube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh"
echo "Waiting to start..."
$($SONAR start)
```

It says `./start.sh: 4: ./start.sh: ~/SonarQube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh: not found` but it does exist. I tried a huge amount of variations it does work only with eval: `eval $SONAR start`.

Comment: I don't have access to a bourne shell at the moment, but you might try adding a -x after the /bin/sh...  "#!/bin/sh -x" which will echo the commands before it executes them.  This might give you more insight into what is actually happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
#!/bin/sh
SONAR=~/"SonarQube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh"
echo "Waiting to start..."
"$SONAR" start
```

Tilde expansion is disabled by quoting (like globbing), so you need to put the tilde outside the quotes.

The last line should not be inside `$()`, as doing this first executes the command, and then expands the content and tries to execute a commande expressed by such content.

Comment: Please try again, I fixed the code, the slash needs to be outside the double quotes too.

Comment: Please note I have added double quotes around the `$SONAR` expansions, in case the path were to contain characters that could trigger word splitting (such as spaces).

Answer (score 3):

Scripts usually use `$HOME` instead of `~`. `$HOME` will expand even inside double quotes.

```
#!/bin/sh
SONAR="$HOME/SonarQube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh"
echo "Waiting to start..."
"$SONAR" start
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `~` between doublequotes, so it's not going to be interpreted as `/home/whatever`.

```
#!/bin/sh
SONAR=~/SonarQube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh
```

Comment: I'm not sure why biowep did that, so since the question isn't about this part, I don't think it's worth changing.

Comment: It sure warrants at least a warning, as someone who needs help with tilde expansion is very likely to not fully understand this line.

Comment: @yoones I wanted to verify the output of the command into an if. For faster read I provided only the minimal ammount of code necessary to expose the problem.

Comment: @biowep OK I removed the line. If this answers your question please accept it as answer.